# Converting a submodule to a folder within a GitHub repo

Tags: macos, github

I'm new to using GitHub and I read up a few of the solutions on stack overflow but I couldn't understand them. 
I pushed a folder in one of my repository and it shows up as a gray submodule. I need it to be a regular directory inside my repo. Can someone simplify what I need to do or show steps because I don't know how to deal with submodules or .gitmodules or where to find them

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't see a .gitmodule at the root of your main repository, that means your subfolder is a nested git repo, recorded as a gitlink (a SHA1 reference), which is what you see as a grayed folder.

All you need to do is:

- delete the .git subfolder you should find in that folder
- go back to the main repo (one folder up)
- add, commit and push: that should push the folder *content* instead of a tree SHA1 reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I managed to delete the subfolder by moving it to a different folder locally and pushing the changes in. How would I  push it in without it being a submodule now?

Comment: @Iamnotabot As I mention in the answer: add commit and push, from the parent folder. If your subfolder does not have a .git, its content will be included.